# Book about a boy who goes to a different planet and fights worm-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been trying to find a book for almost 5 years now.

The book is sci-fi and about a boy who ends up on a different planet. I know he fights worm-like creatures when he first arrives and toward the end we find out he has powers (going through walls I believe).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this an e-book or a physical book?  Do you remember the cover art?  How did he travel from one planet to the other?  (Portal, teleport, fast spaceship, slow spaceship...)  Are the planets around different stars or the same one?

Comment: Kind of sounds like *Dune* :)

Comment: @chepner My first thought as well, but I don't remember Paul going through any walls in that series.  Plenty of other powers, but that wasn't one of them.

Comment: He goes through the Shield Wall near the end, but that isn't by weirding.

Answer (score 5):

Not a lot to go on here, but might this be ***[The Lost Planet](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/17454743)*** (2014) by Rachel Searles...?

This Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/814917356) offers a good overview of the plot, noting that boy wakes up on the planet Trucon. It also mentions that he finds himself in mortal danger from "monsters" that plague Trucon. Whether they're worm-like or not, I can't say:

> **A boy wakes in a room he's never seen before. In fact, he has no memory of anything... not even his name. It's only after the man tending to him finds a chip embedded under the boy's skin that his identity, or at least his name, is discovered: Chase Garrety. Armed with his name and little else, Chase sets out to unravel the mystery of how he ended up on the planet Trucon, wounded and without his memory. He teams up with Parker, the boy who found him unconscious and in mortal danger of the monsters that plague Trucon.** Parker talks Chase into "borrowing" a spaceship that belongs to Parker's mysterious benefactor, in the process, giving the slip to his cyborg nanny/bodyguard. What starts as a joyride soon morphs into danger when Trucon is destroyed in a fiery explosion and the boys unwittingly rescue the man accused of coordinating the attack. As secrets are revealed and Chase is driven by the faintly remembered phrase, "Guide the star," the boys are no longer sure who to trust. Met by danger at every turn, Chase and Parker struggle to stay one step ahead of those who seek them, including the government, the mob, the accused terrorist, and even Parker's guardian.

Another [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2751183042) notes that Chase has powers, including the ability to phase or teleport through walls:

> This book is great. It has a great plot and theme. This story starts off with a boy who woke up on the front lawn of someones house with no clue how he got there or who he is. All he remembers is Guide The Star. He goes on a journey with Parker (The person who lives in the house of the front lawn chase appeared on) and **we learn that Chase has powers like phasing and invincibility. He can teleport through walls and he can not take damage from anything.**

The book was followed by one sequel, *[The Stolen Moon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21469075-the-stolen-moon)* (2015).

Comment: Quickly browsing through the book I can only find one type of monster, and they are described as hard, scaly, black insect-like creatures with wings and many arms. The only worm-like attribute is that they live under ground.